# Installed Fedora 4 times

Tags: linux, fedora

Somehow I manage to  have 4 different bootable fedora on my laptop. How can I delete 3 of them?

Comment: Have You installed Fedora 4 times? Maybe you have only different kernel options at boot time. Please provide output of `cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: ...and output of `fdisk -l`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you managed to install Fedora four times on your machine, what you're seeing are the GRUB options to boot different kernel versions.

Every time the kernel gets updated, GRUB automatically makes it the default option at boot, and creates an option to boot the previous version of the kernel (to be used in case something goes wrong with the new kernel). By default, Fedora keeps the latest 3 old kernels. Therefore it's normal that in your boot screen you see multiple options.

You don't need to remove them. However, should you want to do so, you can remove the old kernels via the command

```
yum remove kernel
```

which removes all kernels except the one in use.
If you want to be safe, you can specify which kernel to remove via the command

```
yum remove kernel-<version>
```

The commands above can be also run by using `dnf` (the new Fedora package manager) instead of `yum`.